# How to Fix : its security certificate is from [missing_subjectAltName]

Tags: ssl, hsts

Today I've stumbled onto a problem :

"This server could not prove that it is" MY_SERVER_NAME "its security certificate is from [missing_subjectAltName]"

This might have happened to you recently as well. Basically your SSL Certificate was not properly set up and was missing its subject alt name.

Why did this happen recently? Because of this : https://textslashplain.com/2017/03/10/chrome-deprecates-subject-cn-matching/

How to fix? Create an SSL Certificate with the subject alt name : 
[How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/27931596#27931596)